# flowplayer cuepoints trouble

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

Hi Sorry for my poor english .I am creating a bubble like cuepoints manually using javascript in flowplayer. on mousehover it will show some information .While page loading itself I want to load all cue points(bubbles). I am having duration in seconds. How do I place my bubbles in appropriate position(time). I am using flowplayer-3.2.16.swf and flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js . so kindly help me .

Answer (score 0):

Cuepoints can be added to the video by adding data-cuepoints to the div holding the video as such:

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-cuepoints="[6, 7, 8, 9]">
    <video preload="none">
        <source src="whatever.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="whatever.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="whatever.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can add the cuepoints via javascript as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    flowplayer.conf.embed = false;
    flowplayer.conf.fullscreen = true;

    flowplayer(function (api) {
        api.cuepoints = [6, 7, 8, 9];

        api.bind("cuepoint", function (e, api, cuepoint) {
            //Execute cuepoint javascript
        });
    });
</script>
```